# Validation in Flex 4.5

Tags: actionscript, flex4.5

I am Rajiv and new to this Flex. Actually, I want to know about the validation part of the script. So, will anybody tell me regarding the scripting for validation in Flex? Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
 Rajiv

Comment: What do you want to validate?

Comment: Regarding the user name, password, user data and other details like name, email, address, ph. no. etc. of the user. So please tell me in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use both server side and client side validation. For the client side validation in flex there are "validator" classes which can be used by MXML tags.

There is detailed documentation on validations here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ff0.html